# (System manufacturer P5K SE) suspend/resume failure (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: suspend, reboot, resume

After the PC went to suspend it doesn't start from the last state. Just does a reboot.
I can suppose that I could wrong configure Asus motherboard but can't find out which one.